# Angular2 EventEmitter fire to parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to fire an Event from the child component to the parent component.

```
 @Component({
 template:'<foo></foo>'
})
 export class ParentComponent{
   onDoSomething($event){
   //do work here
   }

}

@Component({
selector:'foo'
template:<button (click)="onClick($event)">MyButton</button>
})
export class ChildComponent{
   myEvent eventName = new EventEmitter();

   onClick(button){
        this.eventName.emit(button);
   } 

}
```

How do i get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define an `EventEmitter` in your child component with `@Output`

```
@Component({
 selector:'foo',
 template:`<button (click)="onClick($event)">MyButton</button>`
})
export class ChildComponent{
   @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter();

   onClick(button){
        this.myEvent.emit(button);
   } 

}
```

then you "subscribe" to this event in your parent component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Hello World <foo (myEvent)="myEvent($event)"></foo>`,
  directives: [],
  providers: []
})
export class AppComponent {

    myEvent($event){
      console.log(1, $event);
    }
}
```

Full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/MeQbC7Jbc8rprMF66aEF?p=preview

Comment: this still doesn't fire event

Comment: @JT1979 did you check the plunker? Open the console and press the button.

Comment: Any console errors? Maybe you forgot to change something. Maybe `<foo (myEvent)..` in the template?

Comment: I am talking about your plunker. I made to changes so that I added a property called label and the myEvent changes it from hello workd to i worked

Comment: it doesn't fire

Comment: You pressed run at the top of the page, opened your console(F12), pressed the button and didnt see anything in the console?

Comment: yes, that did work. I was mistaken thanks. I didnt have this.label in the event